# Foundation 6 full width row

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

In foundation 6 a full width row is normally defined as 12 columns, but the code below have equal output,

Option #1:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <h1>Welcome to Foundation1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 columns">
  </div>
</div>
```

Option #2:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <h1>Welcome to Foundation1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Option #3:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <h1>Welcome to Foundation1</h1>
</div>
```

They above options do all the same thing but I see option #3 is mostly what is done by web developers. Are there any advantage?

Comment: They don't. Give your `<div>` a `background-color` and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already said:

> a full width row is normally defined as 12 columns

So `.large-6` defines a column with 50% width, `.large-12` will have 100%. Give the cells backgrounds and you'll see. Here is [a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZVBVo).

This is important for line wrapping, so that might be the reason for most developers to go for the full width.

Comment: if I do 12 and 6, is the 6 still in the DOM?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you'll try to have a 12 column cell and a 6 column cell both on a 12 column row... makes no sense, so this of course won't work, the second cell drops beneath the first one. But the easiest way to find out these things: Just try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 20):

in foundation 6 you can usa a "row expanded" to use 100% os screen

```
<div class="row expanded">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

to make a single row width 12 columns in foundation 6 you can use

```
<div class="row column">
     my content
</div>
```

its is equal to first example (without expanded)

Comment: What about the rem padding on the flexbox? We have two `columns small-6` but they are shown below each other because of the padding on the columns. We do not want to use `.collapse` on the row though.

Comment: You can also do:-

`<div class="row column expanded">
     my content
</div>`